# using android animation-list

Tags: android, animation

I'm having a little trouble getting an animated loading spinner to work for a splash page. Nothing shows up when I try to run the following code.  Any suggestions?  It seems that quite a few people have issues with this on google but I do not understand why mine is failing to work.  Thanks!

animationloader.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loadingspinner1" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loadingspinner2" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loadingspinner3" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loadingspinner4" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loadingspinner5" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loadingspinner6" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loadingspinner7" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loadingspinner8" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loadingspinner9" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loadingspinner01" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loadingspinner11" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loadingspinner12" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

SplashScreen.java

```
package com.secure.inmatecanteen;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

    //Beginning the loading animation as we attempt to verify registration with SIP
    ImageView ivLoader = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVloadinganimation);
    ivLoader.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.animationloader);


    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) ivLoader.getBackground();
    frameAnimation.start();
}
}
```

splashscreen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@android:color/white" >

 <ImageView
android:id="@+id/iclogo"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/iclogo"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
/>

 <ImageView
android:id="@+id/IVloadinganimation"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have u included this activity on manifest.xml file?

Comment: Yes I have.  The activity displays without the animation

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Solved my own problem, You cannot start animations in the oncreate.  It has to be in an onclick listener or inside a runnable.

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html you should never call it at onCreate().

Comment: Also, you should consider storing your `animation-list` resource (`animationloader.xml` file) in `res/drawable/` folder, not `res/anim/`! See first example [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation#AnimationDrawable) (see `rocket_thrust.xml` file).

Answer (score 22):

I think the most elegant and versatile option is to extend from the ImageView class:

```
public class Loader extends ImageView {

    public Loader(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public Loader(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public Loader(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loader);
        final AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) getBackground();
        post(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                 frameAnimation.start();
             }
        });
    }
}
```

The loader.xml located in the drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loader_1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loader_2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loader_3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loader_4" android:duration="50" />
    .....
</animation-list>
```

Now include in your views something as simple as this:

```
<com.yourpackage.Loader
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: had 3 devices, could only get this to work on a Nexus 4 running Android 4.2.2, didn't work on honeycomb or gingerbread devices. Will probably have to stick with viewflippers

Comment: I have updated init method adding compatibility with honeycomb & gingerbread. Check it.

Comment: This is a good idea. It's what I was thinking before reading this.
What I've done is go one step further and get the animation from the src attribute, so you can put any animation you wish directly from the xml layout and no code is needed in the MainActivity.

Comment: Awesome. Very simple answer! Works.

Comment: I'm new to Android development. In AndroidStudio, I was suggested to import `import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;`, and I am now getting an error `cannot find symbol variable drawable`. It seems like this class/method should by in the AnimationDrawable library, no?

Answer (score 5):

You can play/start `animation` from `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)` method.

Comment: It is recommended to place it inside `onStart()` which will get called when the view is visible on the screen - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation#tabpanel-kotlin:~:text=It's%20important%20to%20note%20that%20the,makes%20the%20view%20visible%20on%20screen.

Answer (score 4):

**Don't set image resource in xml code.**

My XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
android:id="@+id/splashLayout"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    android:id="@+id/iv_splash"
    android:layout_marginTop="-80dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

In Activity i do

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

ImageView iv_splash;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    iv_splash=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_splash);
    iv_splash.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash);
    final AnimationDrawable progressAnimation =(AnimationDrawable)iv_splash.getBackground();
    progressAnimation.start();
    }
}
```

Drawable file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false" >

<item android:drawable="@drawable/logo" android:duration="400"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/logo1" android:duration="400"/>

</animation-list>
```

It's Working Good  :)

Answer (score 3):

Within this handler the animation is not fully attached to the window, so the animations can’t be started; instead, this is usually done as a result to user action (such as a button press) or within the  `onWindowFocusChangedhandler`.

refer: **professional android 4 application development**

Answer (score 3):

Check GitHub project here I have implemented: [Check here](https://github.com/Andro-Waqar/Android-frame-animation-using-Animation-List)

**My MainActivity.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/animation_imageview"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/animation_frame"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/animation_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:text="Converting Please wait..."/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My animation-list in drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_covert_f1" android:duration="90"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_covert_f2" android:duration="90"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_covert_f3" android:duration="90"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_covert_f4" android:duration="90"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_covert_f5" android:duration="90"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_covert_f6" android:duration="90"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_covert_f7" android:duration="90"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_covert_f8" android:duration="90"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_covert_f9" android:duration="90"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_covert_f10" android:duration="90"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_covert_f11" android:duration="90"/>

</animation-list>
```

**My MainActivty.java**

Always remember to use Runnable to start the animation

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AnimationDrawable progressAnimation;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.animation_imageview);
        progressAnimation =    (AnimationDrawable)imageView.getDrawable();
        progressAnimation.setCallback(imageView);
        progressAnimation.setVisible(true, true);
        imageView.post(new Starter());
    }

    class Starter implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            progressAnimation.start();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: ScreenShot]

**Works Perfectly Good Luck :)**

Answer (score 1):

Elegant solution - create your own Animated View which will follow life-cycle rules.

```
public class AnimatedImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {
    public AnimatedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                context, R.drawable.animated_icon));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        // It's important to note that the start() method called on 
        // the AnimationDrawable cannot be called during the onCreate() 
        // method of your Activity, because the AnimationDrawable
        // is not yet fully attached to the window.
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        AnimationDrawable tapAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) getDrawable();
        tapAnimation.start();
    }
}
```

here is animated_icon.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tap_icon_1" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tap_icon_2" android:duration="500" />
</animation-list>
```