# Animation-list not working - shows only the first element

Tags: android, android-animation

**Problem:**
Shows only the first element in the animation-list.

**Animation list drawable file in res/drawable:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false" >

  <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/k2si"
    android:duration="1000"/>
  <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/android"
    android:duration="1000"/>

</animation-list>
```

**Starting the animation:**

```
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.screensaver_image);
    ((AnimationDrawable) image.getBackground()).start();
```

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html) (scroll to Frame animation)

Comment: What are your drawables?

Comment: where are you calling the start() method from.  If it is in the onCreate of your activity it won't work.

Comment: @Mike - yes it is in `onCreate()`. What is the correct life cycle method to call out the start?

Comment: Answering my own question: `onWindowFocusChanged()` is the correct method to call out `start()`

Comment: yep, I had the same issue with an animation.

Comment: I have tried Works awesome<br>
Check this thread: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56348279/9475689)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please see the similar question here

[Starting frame by frame animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785336/starting-frame-by-frame-animation)

you will get an idea about frame by frame animation.

If you didn't understood check the link below, good tutorial for frame by frame animation using XML file.

[frame by frame xml animation with google android](http://www.twintechs.com/2008/06/frame-by-frame-xml-animation-with-google-android/)

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve same thing from layout xml itself,

just mentioned `android:src="@drawable/rode_anim"`  which is nothing but your custom animation-list drawable.

Comment: After Lollipop xml autostart of animation doesn't work any more.