# Element item is not allowed here (animation-list)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-animation, splash-screen, animationdrawable

I'm using Android Studio 3.1.3. I was trying to build a splash screen using animation-list. I have some .png images in my res/drawable folder and I have this current .xml file in the same folder.

But it is showing this message:
[Element item is not allowed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U11bj.jpg)

Here's the piece of the code from the .xml file:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:oneshot="true" >

        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/splash00"
            android:duration="100"/>
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/splash01"
            android:duration="100"/>
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/splash02"
            android:duration="100"/>
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/splash03"
            android:duration="100"/>
               .
               .
               .

</animation-list>
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is there an unclosed `<item` before the errors?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721458/using-android-animation-list
שאלה דומה

Comment: The code you provided compiles fine on my pc. Please provide a complete MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve